# Paypal Integration Invalid HTTP response The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal

In my local host it's work fine sandbox account but live server i'm testing with same sandbox but throw the exception

```
(Invalid HTTP response The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.)
```

on the line

```
on PayResponse payResponse = adaptivePaymentsService.Pay(request);
```

My code:

```
PayRequest request = new PayRequest(new RequestEnvelope("en_US"), "PAY",
                       cancelUrl, currency,
                       receiverList, returnUrl);
        request.reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError = true;
        request.ipnNotificationUrl = redirectUrl;

        Dictionary<string, string> sdkConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        sdkConfig.Add("mode", "sandbox");
        sdkConfig.Add("account1.apiUsername", apiusername);
        sdkConfig.Add("account1.apiPassword", apipassword);
        sdkConfig.Add("account1.apiSignature", apisignature);
        sdkConfig.Add("account1.applicationId", applicationid);

        AdaptivePaymentsService adaptivePaymentsService = new AdaptivePaymentsService(sdkConfig);
        PayResponse payResponse = adaptivePaymentsService.Pay(request);
        string paykey = payResponse.payKey;

        if (!payResponse.responseEnvelope.ack.ToString().Trim().ToUpper().Equals(AckCode.FAILURE.ToString())
   && !payResponse.responseEnvelope.ack.ToString().Trim().ToUpper().Equals(AckCode.FAILUREWITHWARNING.ToString()))
        {
            return Redirect("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=" + paykey);
        }
```

please any one guide me  thanks in advance

Comment: You might be running into the TLS 1.2 issue.  Make sure your server is using TLS 1.2 for all HTTP requests by default.  Alternatively, there may be a way to force TLS 1.2 from your code.  I'm not a Java guy, though, so you'll have to do some Googling for that.

Comment: thanks for your response can u give some code guidance to adaptive split payment using rest api in asp.net mvc3 if u not know about that means just give php code

Comment: The Adaptive Payments API and the REST API are different products.  If you're wanting to do a split you'll need to use Adaptive.  You could also use Express Checkout if you're doing a parallel payment, but EC doesn't support chained.

Comment: thanks for your replay i'm update TLS 1.2 sandbox work fine with above  code i'm got above code in google i'm submit my application and got app id where i'm get SIGNATURE USERID and PASSWORD for adaptive api please guide me.